# php counter for webpage with GET variable for each page variable

Tags: php

i use this

> ```
> <?php   $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r"); if(!$handle){
>    echo "could not open the file" ;   } else {
>
>
> $counter = (int ) fread($handle,20);
> fclose ($handle);
> $counter++;
> echo" <strong> you are visitor no ". $counter . " </strong> " ; $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ); fwrite($handle,$counter) ;
> ```
>
> fclose ($handle) ;
>       } ?>

but its makes a counter for the page tst.php every entry.

i want to make counting for this page tst.php?id=1

but if i change to tst.php?id=2 to store this data to but from zero and counting.

and then return to tst,php?id=1 and showing the continuing counting of visits to this page.

and the another tst.php?id=....

for every id page!

Comment: Have you thought about switching over to a DB solution? It would work so much better, and it wouldn't clutter up your web dirs.

Comment: no i want somting like this to have acces more simply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
   <?php
$const='counter';
$id=$_GET['id'];
$ext='.txt';
if(file_exists($const.$id.$ext))
{
$file=fopen($const.$id.$ext,'r');
$data=fread($file,filesize($const.$id.$ext));
fclose($file);
$file=fopen($const.$id.$ext,'w');
fwrite($file,$data+1);
}
else
{
$file=fopen($const.$id.$ext,'w+');
fwrite($file,1);
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

This will create files for each 'id' that you pass in the url.
Copy the above code in file for ex: counter.php and include in the file wherever the counter is required as :

```
<?php
include "counter.php"
?>
```

Hope this resolves your issue!

Comment: $file=fopen('counter.txt'.$_GET["id"],w);

Comment: this dosent work, is posible to make if statement that if the file dose not exist to created an the read fro there. but if it exist only to read the content?

Comment: Can you now try the code? The syntax for fopen was incorrect. I have not coded in php lately. Sorry for that.

Comment: i,ve made the change but i, dont want to creat files for every id. it is posible to created bi the php code?

Comment: fopen(/cnt/counter.txt2585) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: Okay I have changed the code again fopen("filename",w+) helps you to create files if they don't exist. Hope the issue is resolved??

Comment: Can you try 'x' instead of w+ in fopen permissions??

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in $file=fopen("'counter.txt'.$_GET["id"]",r);

Comment: Okay try this $const='counter' $id=$_GET['id'] and replace the filename in fopen with $const.$id in single quotes. Does it works??

Comment: I have changed the code for you. Just copy paste. Your issue is resolved. A small error in formatting of script. Try the new code.

Comment: I have ran the above code in my server its working fine. Try on your machine I hope there's no more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a page is loaded, consider using [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/parse_url) to determine the end query string. Enter that into your file.

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Comment: Nothing at all, I guess I just felt like sharing a different method!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a separate counter for every page.
If yes, here is an edited version of your code:

```
$fp = fopen('counter'.intval($_GET['id']).'.txt', 'r+');

while(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
// waiting to lock the file 
}

$counter = intval(fread($fp, filesize('counter'.intval($_GET['id']).'.txt'))); $counter++;

ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file 
fwrite($fp, $counter);  // set your data 
fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock 
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock

fclose($fp);
```

I put the id into the filename.

---

Edit:
To make it in one counter.txt file(it is inefficient):

```
$fh = fopen('counter.txt', 'c+'); //Open file
while(!flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {} //Lock file
$var = json_decode(fread($fh, filesize('counter.txt'))); //Json decode file to array
if(isset($var)) $var[(int)$_GET['id']]++; else $var[(int)$_GET['id']] = 1; //Increment the id's array value by one
ftruncate($fh, 0); //Erase file contents
fwrite($fh, json_encode($var)); //Write json encoded array
fflush($fh); //Flush to file
flock($fh, LOCK_UN); //Unlock file
fclose($fh); //Close file
```

**But as said by h2ooooooo, a DB based solution will be better.**(I will write it if you want)

Comment: i've changed my code this works but its the same! i need for everi id!

Comment: This uses the same technique as the another answer but a bit more secure, and it is my idea(we posted it at the same time:)) And, I think it is better to make a separate file for every id. Because if you have many ids, the script will have to parse a larger file. But i write it if you _really_ want.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, which will work same way as your code except storing counter for individual id in individual file:

```
$fp = fopen("counter.txt".$_GET["id"], "r+");

while(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    // waiting to lock the file }

$counter = intval(fread($fp, filesize("counter.txt".$_GET["id"]))); $counter++;

ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file fwrite($fp, $counter);  // set your data fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: i've changed my code this works but its the same! i need for everi id!

Comment: @user3329634 Yes it is for every id, as we are appending $_GET["id"] in the file name. So it will create individual files like counter.txt1, counter.txt2, ... for individual ids and store $counter value over there. Now if you can elaborate what different you require.

Comment: i know that but i have 2000 id's i dont want to create 2000 count.txt files is posible to store all data in one cont txt for every id?

Comment: Though this will work, still like @h2ooooooo I would suggest to use DB approach as that would be more straight forward.

Comment: i'm new in php and i like to make somting simple!

Comment: For that you can store $counter in individual lines ie for id=1 store in statement 1, for id = 2 in statement 2. Code will be a bit more complex. Or think of using xml instead with individual id as nodes.